# Flutter Provider desde main

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am developing a login for my application and I have a provider that verifies if the user is logged in or not, in order to redirect him to the corresponding route, the problem is that I want to execute that provider from the main so that it loads as soon as possible, the provider that I want to run is this.

Provider.of(context).listarUsuarios()

This is the code of my main:

```
import 'package:amigo_almacen/pages/pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Providers/DataProviders.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductoProvider(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ReporteProvider(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GestUsuarios(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Getcomidas(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GetFormReportes(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GestRopa(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GetBebidas(), lazy: false),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SessionUser(), lazy: false),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo),
        title: 'Amigo_Almacen',
        initialRoute: LoginPage.routeName,
        routes: {
          //Fredy Nemesio Palomino Huamani
          LoginPage.routeName: (_) => const LoginPage(),
          RegistroPage.routeName: (_) => const RegistroPage(),
          RecuperarPage.routeName: (_) => const RecuperarPage(),
          Recuperar_pages2.routeName: (_) => const Recuperar_pages2(),
          PrincipalPage.routeName: (context) => const PrincipalPage(),
          OptionsForm.routeName: (_) => const OptionsForm(),
          SuccessPage.routeName: (context) => SuccessPage('', '', '', '', ''),
          //Victor Vicente Palomino Torres
          ComidaPage.routeName: (_) => const ComidaPage(),
          //Valentino Gómez Aguirre
          BebidasPage.routeName: (_) => const BebidasPage(),
          //Axel David Chambilla Obregón
          RopaPage.routeName: (_) => const RopaPage(),
          //Anabel Huanca Moreano
          ReportesPage.routeName: (_) => const ReportesPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Consumer in your home: whenever the use is authenticated it will change the home page depends on what you choose here is an example:

child: Consumer(
builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'MyShop',
theme: ThemeData(
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
),
textTheme: const TextTheme(
subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
subtitle2: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
headline5:
TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20))),
home: auth.isAuth
? ProductOverviewScreen()
: FutureBuilder(
future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
builder: (ctx, snapshot) =>
snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
? const SplashScreen()
: AuthScreen()),